# Comparing two strings with OR in PHP

Tags: php

I am trying to compare two strings and also I am using OR operator in PHP

Here is the Code:

```
<?php

    $admintext= "Yes";

    if(strcmp($admintext, 'Yes') != 0 or strcmp($admintext, 'No') != 0)
    {
         echo " Not perfect, Admin text doesn't have Yes OR No text"; 
    }
    else
    {
        echo " Perfect, Admin text has Yes or No";
    }
?>
```

with the above code, I am always getting Not perfect, not sure why? What is wrong? - If I remove code after OR this work perfectly.

Thanks!

Comment: I am sure, you know when to use `&&` and `||`. Because, output is common sense, it's obviously second condition will get satisfied, so it will return true.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to join the conditions with `and`, nor `or`:

```
if (strcmp($admintext, 'Yes') != 0 and strcmp($admintext, 'No') != 0) {
     echo " Not perfect, Admin text doesn't have Yes OR No text"; 
}
else {
    echo " Perfect, Admin text has Yes or No";
}
```

The reason for lies in the [DeMorgan's logic laws](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws).  Consider the expression `A or B`, where `A` represent yes is present, and `B` represents no is present:

```
A V B
!(A V B)
!A ^ !B
```

Comment: Perfect. Thanks!